# display list of cancelled and errored workflows?

Tags: workflow

This is for SP2010. I've got a list that has a number of workflows bound to it. The list has a few hundred list items in it, and I'm trying to troubleshoot why some workflows are failing.

On a per-item basis, I can go into "View Workflow History", and look to see if there are any entries in the "Cancelled and Errored Workflows" section.

Is there a way to generate a report or list of all the items in the list which have cancelled or errored workflows, so I can quickly see which list items are involved?

Answer (score 0):

Alan, do you have access to the content database? You should be able to get it from there. That's where the report data comes from.

Look at the WorkflowUsageTelemetry view in your logging database. You'll have to join that with the view of ListIDs and WorkflowIDs, so you know what is what.

Let me know if you need more help. I wasn't able to find an example online. I'll try to write the SQL and post it here if you like.

Comment: I have avoided directly accessing any of the databases, as that is considered forbidden territory by Microsoft. Doubtless the answer does lie within there, though.

Comment: You're not altering the data or configuration, just querying what's already there.